# in python how can i add a column (next to the index column) with the values 1,2,3,4,etc until the end of the column

Tags: python

```
    location      date      
0   Afghanistan 24-02-20    
1   Afghanistan 25-02-20    
2   Afghanistan 26-02-20    
3   Afghanistan 27-02-20    
4   Afghanistan 28-02-20
```

Comment: A column in what? [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, the above is a DataFrame, you can use the following to obtain the result:

```
df.insert(0, 'ID', range(1, 1+len(df)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
Locations = ['Afghanistan','USA','Canada','France','UK']
Dates = ['24-02-20','25-02-20','26-02-20','27-02-20','28-02-20']

for i in range(len(list(zip(Locations,Dates)))):
  print(f"{i} {Locations[i]} {Dates[i]}")
```

zip() prevents bugs if a list is longer than the other

Output:

```
0 Afghanistan 24-02-20
1 USA 25-02-20
2 Canada 26-02-20
3 France 27-02-20
4 UK 28-02-20
```